# How find this value $2b_k^4+8b_k^3b_{k-1}+24b_k^2b_{k-1}^2+32b_kb_{k-1}^3+14b_{k-1}^4-48b_{k-1}^2b_{k-2}^2-32b_{k-2}^4$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> let sequence $\{b_{n}\}$ such $$b_{n}=-b_{n-1}-2b_{n-2}(n\ge 3),b_{1}=1,b_{2}=-1$$
>   show that
>   $$
> 2b_k^4+8b_k^3b_{k-1}+24b_k^2b_{k-1}^2+32b_kb_{k-1}^3+14b_{k-1}^4-48b_{k-1}^2b_{k-2}^2-32b_{k-2}^4=0$$

My try:since
$$b_{k}=-b_{k-1}-2b_{k-2}$$
so
$$2(-b_{k-1}-2b_{k-2})^4+24(-b_{k-1}-2b_{k-2})^2b^2_{k-1}+32(-b_{k-1}-2b_{k-2})b^3_{k-1}+14b_{k-1}^4-48b_{k-1}^2b_{k-2}^2-32b_{k-2}^4\neq 0$$

see  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%28x%2B2y%29%5E4%2B24%28x%2B2y%29%5E2*x%5E2%2B32%28-x-2y%29*x%5E3%2B14x%5E4-48x%5E2*y%5E2-32y%5E3

My methods is wrong? so How can prove it? Thank you

and By the way this problem is from this:[Does this sequence always give a square number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513204/does-this-sequence-always-give-a-square-number)

But I find this red part maybe is not equals zero,(so this proof is not complete)

Comment: Why somebody wanna produce such a perplex identity for that simple recursive relation?

Comment: @Shuchang,I have edit this problem background

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving

Comment: @labbhattacharjee,I found this methods is very very ugly.someone have other methods?Thank you

Comment: What happened to your second term?(it looks like the one with $8$ as coefficient went to Narnia...)

Answer (score 2):

$2b_k^4+8b_k^3b_{k-1}+24b_k^2b_{k-1}^2+32b_kb_{k-1}^3+14b_{k-1}^4-48b_{k-1}^2b_{k-2}^2-32b_{k-2}^4$

$ = (2b_k^4+8b_k^3b_{k-1}+12b_k^2b_{k-1}^2+8b_kb_{k-1}^3+2b_{k-1}^4)+12b_k^2b_{k-1}^2+24b_kb_{k-1}^3+12b_{k-1}^4-48b_{k-1}^2b_{k-2}^2-32b_{k-2}^4$

$= 2(b_k+b_{k-1})^4+12(b_k^2b_{k-1}^2+2b_kb_{k-1}^3+b_{k-1}^4)-48b_{k-1}^2b_{k-2}^2-32b_{k-2}^4$

$= 32b_{k-2}^4+12b_{k-1}^2(-2b_{k-2})^2-48b_{k-1}^2b_{k-2}^2-32b_{k-2}^4$

$= 0$

Answer (score 1):

Given $$ x=b_k, \; \;  y = b_{k-1},  \; \; z = b_{k-2},  $$ your polynomial is double
$$ \left( x^2 + 2 x y + 4 y^2  \right)^2 -  \left( 3 y^2 +  4 z^2  \right)^2 $$
However, $$ x = -y - 2 z.  $$
So $$ x^2 + 2 x y + 4 y^2 = (x+y) + 3 y^2 = (-2z)^2 + 3 y^2 = 4 z^2 + 3 y^2, $$ and
this equals
$$  3y^2 + 4 z^2.  $$
The squaring does not change the equality.